# Class 'Stripe' not found -- Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I've run command 'composer require stripe/stripe-php'

I am getting this error ---- **Class 'Stripe' not found**.

**Here's my controller-**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
class StripeController extends Controller
{
    public function stripePost(Request $request)
    {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey ( 'sk_test_51IqDEDyMvZ4TU4ArtfN0olk7c9oXEGgATFIueO8SIEmrTv3vZFEMgBXOy4wNNCCSA4lueR84PyEwbzpp6W2QW' );
    try {
        \Stripe\Charge::create ( array (
                "amount" => $request->amount * 100,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $request->input ( 'stripeToken' ), // obtained with Stripe.js
                "description" => "Test payment." 
        ) );
        Session::flash ( 'success-message', 'Payment done successfully !' );
        return Redirect::back ();
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        Session::flash ( 'fail-message', "Error! Please Try again." );
        return Redirect::back ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Charge;

class StripeController extends Controller
{
    public function stripePost(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR_API_KEY');
        Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => 'customerId',
            'amount'   => 1,
            'currency' => 'usd'
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use auto import extension, if you are using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I dont know about other editors but auto import is helpfully in VS code it just insert the namespace for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be requiring the file:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#composer